# Visual Studio 2012 Object Browser unused references

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, objectbrowser

I removed some unused references from a Visual Studio 2012 Project (Visual Basic), yet they still show up in my Object Browser (F2).

Does anyone have a clue how to remove those entries?

Comment: Well okay, I just solved it.
I still had the .dlls in the bin-directory. Deleted them and they show up no more.

Now why do I have to wait 6 hours to answer my own question? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still had the .dlls in the bin-directory. Deleted them and they show up no more.

Answer (score 0):

*The Object Browser allows you to select and examine the symbols available for use in projects. You can open the Object Browser from the View menu, or by clicking the Object Browser button on the main toolbar.
There are three panes: an Objects pane on the left, a Members pane on the upper right, and a Description pane on the lower right. If you resize the Object Browser into a single column, the Objects pane moves to the top, the Members pane to the middle, and the Description pane to the bottom.**strong text***

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned, rebuilt, turned it off and on again...
I even did a full text search in the solution directory and windows couldn't find anything inside the files..

Comment: Downvoting your. Not an answer.